# How can to run python unittests in Django in debug mode with PyCharm using local settings?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have local settings for my `Django` project. I run applicatin with `./manage.py runserver --settings=settings.local` command.

I have following settings for `Unittests`
[image]

But when I press `Debug Unittests for test.t...` I get error

```
/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/onedeeds/bin/python /home/m0nte-cr1st0/.local/share/umake/ide/pycharm/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py --target core.test.test_views.ReactivateAccountViewTestCase
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest core.test.test_views.ReactivateAccountViewTestCase in /home/m0nte-cr1st0/pet_projects/onedeeds/onedeeds/core

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.local/share/umake/ide/pycharm/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 159, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/pet_projects/onedeeds/onedeeds/core/test/test_views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/onedeeds/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Token(models.Model):
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/onedeeds/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py", line 15, in Token
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='auth_token',
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/onedeeds/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/m0nte-cr1st0/.virtualenvs/onedeeds/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 64, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting AUTH_USER_MODEL, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**settings/base.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "core.User"
```

**settings/local.py**

```
from .base import *
```

**structure og the project**

```
onedeeds/
  onedeeds/
    app1/
      ...
      test/
    app2/
      ...
      test/
    settings/
      base.py
      local.py
    manage.py
```

Comment: Are you using pycharm community or professional? Are you using the default test runner or pytest?

Comment: @MattSeymour I use `PyCharm Community Edtion 2019.1.3`. For testing I use `./manage.py test`

Comment: Are you sure your screenshot is for the unit testing run configuration?  It doesn't look the same as mine (though I'm not using community edition.  Your file name is "onedeeds". Does that really only have unittests in it?

Comment: @FiddleStix `oneneeds` - it's a main folder which consists `manage.py` file (*updated image in the post*).  
The screenshot shows how I tried to configure, but, apparently, something is wrong there.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace too?

Comment: @FiddleStix added full `traceback` and `structure` of the project

Comment: You've got a zero in DJANG0_SETTINGS_MODULE where you should have an "oh".  As in, "oh dear, I shouldn't have typed that environment variable name out by hand"!

Comment: @FiddleStix 
Sorry, but I do not quite understand what you mean (

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук Look _very_ carefully at the image you attached.  See where it says "DJANG0_SETTINGS_MODULE"? It should say "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE".  I don't think I can make it any clearer than that.

Comment: @FiddleStix is right.